# How can I get test coverage around AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

So I'm shooting for 100% coverage on an MVC3 site, and we're using areas.  I can get coverage on everything else EXCEPT for this one line in `Application_Start`:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

I've already thoroughly tested each area's registration, so this really amounts to an integration test of sorts, but **I'd still like to cover this somehow** without having to resort to a CoverageExclude attribute or lowering the coverage percentage.

Note that unit testing this in NUnit this explodes with the following exception snippet:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage. at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel trying to aim for 100% test coverage on an application is not always the best approach. Sure your app should be well tested but pushing everything aside to make sure you have 100% coverage stops you focusing on the quality of the tests and more about the coverage. Coverage is just a rough guide and does not tell you if your tests are actually testing what they should be only that "line x" got called.

Having high TC is good but I'd say if there's 100% you're not testing properly. personally I wouldn't test this.

Comment: I completely agree with you, and ultimately I will be excluding this with coverage filters.  I'm just curious if it's possible to truly unit test anything that invokes the build manager in this way.

Comment: The more I have milled on this answer the more I feel it is my ethical duty to accept it.  After all, it's all about "working software that matters," not achieving artificial metrics of working software that may or may not matter.  Thanks for snapping me out of my previous state...even though I will always wonder if it was cover-able.

Comment: Glad you've seen the light :P

Comment: @brandon-linton, even though I completely agree with Sara, I don't think this should be marked as the answer, simply because it doesn't answer the question! (Someone else with the same problem will get no help from this.)

Comment: @BrandonLinton while achieving 100% test coverage is not productive, test coverage of your routes for anything more than a trivial application *is* important.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? All your saying is don't strive for 100% coverage but you didn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the code that populates routes to a method that takes RouteCollection as a parameter.
You can then call it in your test passing an empty collection and verify that it contains all the routes you need.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

     routes.MapRoute(
        "Default_without_optional_params", // Route name
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
     );
 }


    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

The same applies to Areas. Extract a method that takes `AreaRegistrationContext`.

Comment: I have test coverage around the route in the way that you describe.  I was just wondering if there's any way to test the Application_Start method if you have `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` in it, because it doesn't appear it can be called outside of a running web application.

Comment: Oh, I see. You probably need a strategy pattern here: extract an interface IAreaRegistration and implement it on 2 classes: FullAreaRegistration and TestAreaRegistration. Test one will do nothing and you can use it in you tests.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the thoughts Jakub.  I've got the area routes themselves well-tested.  I could never quite snag the one line (curly brace) after the all-areas registration, so I just redirected my efforts to exclusion filters in TeamCity.

Comment: @JakubKonecki, could you please elaborate on what `The same applies to Areas. Extract a method that takes AreaRegistrationContext.` actually means? Preferably with some code. (Because I have extracted the method, and now I have no idea what argument to call it with.)

Comment: Pass a new instance of `AreaRegistrationContext` - or a mock - you can than test if all the expected routes were registered.